# Drupal taxonomy view

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

i would like to generate a view of taxonomy terms in a way that the latest node related to each term populate e.g if i have three terms what i want a view where the result should look like this

term1->latest node

term2->latest node

term3->latest node

term4->latest node

i want the latest node for each term if i add a term in vocabulary it automatically added in this page i hope you understand my question please help me out how i can do that

thanx.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will be able to do something very close using [Viewes](http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/147).  Chose Taxonomy: Term under Arguments, and then the Node Title etc, then you will have to adjust the items to display parameter.